# Statefulset Tolerations not propagating to pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Statefulset definition which has Tolerations under spec.template.spec. This is in line with spec.template.spec.containers.

```
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: workers
    value: "true"
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
```

Statefulset is showing the tolerations workers = true. But the pods are only showing node.kubernetes.io/not-ready and node.kubernetes.io/unreachable. Any idea why it is happening like this? I tried many options but nothing seem to work.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but deployment-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly that tolerations was added to statefullset after pods was created? u can try edit manifest, if it not in running state.